# How to retain the index count of dataframe from 1?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
test = {'name': ['mnop', 'abcd', 'ijkl', 'efgh'], 'value': ['dfdf', 'jkjhk', 'cndlkcn', 'njnck']}
df = pd.DataFrame(test)
print(df)
```

Above code prints data as below

```
name    value
0  mnop     dfdf
1  abcd    jkjhk
2  ijkl  cndlkcn
3  efgh    njnck
```

Now, I would like to sort it by name and index starting from `1 to 4` and then sequentially.
I tried, `print(df.sort_values(by=['name']))`
but index retains it's original association as below:

```
name    value
1  abcd    jkjhk
3  efgh    njnck
2  ijkl  cndlkcn
0  mnop     dfdf
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Do you mean `df.index = range(1, 5)` ?

Comment: @Mortz : Yeah, kind of but without providing range, just with starting pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sorting point is correct and you can use the parameter `ignore_index = True` to have a new index

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['name'], ignore_index = True)
```

Since you then want to have an idea starting from 1 (and not 0) you have to add 1 with

```
df.index += 1
```

Comment: Was trying with 'sort_index', 'ignore_index', something I missed it. Thank you @Dasim

Comment: You're welcome and welcome to stack overflow! please remember to mark your question as answered to repay my work https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks for that. It was asking me to wait for sometime to accept answer.